# Taking ownership of task schedules and registery entries

Tags: windows

In my Windows 8.1 game server, I've been trying to disable some tasks scheduled via taskschd.msc and remove some registery entries using regedit,

but it looks like I lack required permissions.

How can I get it done?

- All tasks and entries relate to the beloved GWX windows 10 installation forcer

Answer (score 0):

Note thing to note is that GWX goes away with the recent [kb3184143](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3184143) This would eliminate the need to disable anything manually.